# How to execute Python scripts from HTML button

Tags: php, python, html, python-3.x

My html page has a button and when I click that button I need to execute a python file. I don't need to show the python file content in browser, I only need to execute the python file by clicking the html button. When executing the python file, it will generate a json file which I need.

This is my code and it's opening the python file but not showing any output.

```
<html>
<body>

<h1> DEVELOPMENT </h1>

<form action="phpfile.php" method="post">
<input type="submit" name="someAction" value="GO" />
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

```
 <?php

 $result_last_line = system("python C:/xampp/htdocs/NEW/pythonfile/identifyrooms.py");
 header('Location: view.html');
 exit;
 ?>
```

When I run my python file using editor the output console is as below.
[image: Output of python file in editor]

Can anyone find the error?.
Thanks

Comment: Well, you typically would write a Web Server **in python** to achieve a better result.

Comment: I found the solution. There was an error in my python file. I found the error using apache log file.

Comment: Feel free to post how you found your solution below as an answer

Comment: The above code I mentioned is correct and has no issue. So I checked the error log file which is in C:\xampp\apache\logs folder. There I found the error saying,    

ImportError: No module named MySQLdb    
The syntax of the command is incorrect.    
    
So I removed that import statement since I didn't use it.